# bulk index in Elasticsearch only if doc is absent

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

using elasticsearch bulk api one can index the docs as follows:

```
 for doc in shingles:
            actions.append({
                "_op_type": "index",
                "_index": index_name,
                '_id': hashed_id,
                "content_completion": {
                    "input": [doc],
                    "weight": 1
                }
            })
    helpers.bulk(self.es, actions)
```

But what I need is to index data only and if only the doc is not present in the index. How can I achieve this using bulk API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in elastic search while indexing document

if you set op_type=create then it will only create documents if it does not exists otherwise it will fail and return errors for those document

```
POST _bulk/
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" ,**"op_type":"create"** } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

Here is a link for the same.

Comment: but this causes the failure of the whole operation. If the first doc be a duplicate, the rest of the docs will never be indexed

Comment: no it will execute all the operations in bulk and return you status for each operation.